# SharePoint asks for Credentials twice after Configuring AAM and SSL

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping, ssl

I am successfully able to configure SSL and redirecting users from HTTP to HTTPS using AAM.

Here are the settings I've used in AAM-

**Public URLs**

```
    URL                               Zone
    http://sharepoint                 Default
    https://subsite.site.com          Internet
```

**Internal URLs**

```
    URL                               Zone
    http://subsite.site.com          Internet
```

I want to achieve this only with Central Administrator. I don't want to edit my web.config file or edit URL Rewrite in IIS.

Please suggest me on how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

if you configure the SSL certs at IIS, then i think following the AAM settings will fix the issue. You need to add internal urls

```
  Internal URL              Zone           Public URL for Zone 
 http://subsite.site.com        Default     https://subsite.site.com    
 https://subsite.site.com   Default     https://subsite.site.com
```

Comment: If I put `https://subsite.site.com` as default public URL then I think it would not load the site at all..because in IIS site is at http://sharepoint

Comment: why you think this? what are your IIS settings? if you want redirect http to https from sharepoint to subsite.site.com

Comment: According to these settings, if user tries to open `http://subsite.site.com` then it won't load at all, right?

Comment: no, from this settings if you try to open http://sharepoint then it will redirect to https://subsite.site.com

Comment: Ok, I think you misunderstood this. `http://sharepoint` is url which can only be accessed from the server. It's like localhost:12345.

Comment: what is your goal? you want access the site using the https://subsite.site.com? check the updated answer, i think now it should work...even if you type http then it will redirect https

Comment: Help me understanding this..when I created new website in sharepoint server, its local URL was `http://sharepoint`. So to achieve what you have updated..should I update my IIS bindings for this site to use hostname `http://subsite.site.com`?

Comment: do you have the DNS record which point to the that server? in your case subsite.sit.com...after that you have to update the IIS bindings to attach the SSL certs with the port on which you want to configure it

Comment: Yes we have and it SSL is configured.

Comment: if IIS is already setup then update the AAM settings and test it

Comment: I have done this. But still SharePoint asks for credentials twice

Comment: have u configured kerberos authentication? try to add the site into the trusted sites of the IE and try again?

Comment: i have not configured kerberos ..and adding site to trusted didn't help either

Comment: Could you please use fiddler and check  on which thing authentication is triggering? may be the SSL certs?

Comment: Fiddler: When the site first run the Protocol was HTTP and browser asked for credentials. After login, it redirected to HTTPS protocol and browser asked for credentials again.
I'm new to fiddler, please let me know what information you want me to provide using fiddler.